Get recent tags of a repo using github rest api
I'm trying to use github rest api to get latest tags of some repos, but sometimes the api returns very early tags, why? Must I use graphql instead in such cases?
request line: https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tags?per_page=5
[
{
    "name": "weekly.2012-03-27",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/zipball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-27",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tarball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-27",
    "commit": {
        "sha": "3895b5051df256b442d0b0af50debfffd8d75164",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/commits/3895b5051df256b442d0b0af50debfffd8d75164"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMjMwOTY5NTk6cmVmcy90YWdzL3dlZWtseS4yMDEyLTAzLTI3"
},
{
    "name": "weekly.2012-03-22",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/zipball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-22",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tarball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-22",
    "commit": {
        "sha": "da7959d5dd1a230868d8eca9dbf11b4d54e8915a",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/commits/da7959d5dd1a230868d8eca9dbf11b4d54e8915a"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMjMwOTY5NTk6cmVmcy90YWdzL3dlZWtseS4yMDEyLTAzLTIy"
},
{
    "name": "weekly.2012-03-13",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/zipball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-13",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tarball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-13",
    "commit": {
        "sha": "9ef03fdf7778f23aa304a03888e4e0f698a3ef84",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/commits/9ef03fdf7778f23aa304a03888e4e0f698a3ef84"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMjMwOTY5NTk6cmVmcy90YWdzL3dlZWtseS4yMDEyLTAzLTEz"
},
{
    "name": "weekly.2012-03-04",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/zipball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-04",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tarball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-03-04",
    "commit": {
        "sha": "56208edb8dfc297efde71f18730dfb09b3dcb928",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/commits/56208edb8dfc297efde71f18730dfb09b3dcb928"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMjMwOTY5NTk6cmVmcy90YWdzL3dlZWtseS4yMDEyLTAzLTA0"
},
{
    "name": "weekly.2012-02-22",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/zipball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-02-22",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tarball/refs/tags/weekly.2012-02-22",
    "commit": {
        "sha": "6419bbbfd310d0e48b3de60c8891a8f0fcc98b6f",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/commits/6419bbbfd310d0e48b3de60c8891a8f0fcc98b6f"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMjMwOTY5NTk6cmVmcy90YWdzL3dlZWtseS4yMDEyLTAyLTIy"
}

]
